# Problem with homegrown Concat method

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I've implemented my own `String` class, and need to write `Concat` method.

I can't get it work.

My code is:

```
//the m_str is private member which is initialize in the c-tor
//this function is get a string and concat it with the original string
String &String::Concat(const char *string)
{
    int original_str_size = length(m_str);
    int other_str_size = length(string);
    int needed_length = original_str_size + other_str_size + 1;

    char *str_copy = m_str;

    del();

    m_str = new char[needed_length];
    m_size = needed_length;

    int index = 0;

    for(; index < original_str_size; index++)
    {
        if(index < original_str_size)
            m_str[index] = str_copy[index];
        else
            m_str[index] = string[index];
    }

    m_str[index] = 0;

    return *this;
}
```

The problem in the `Concat` method is that I wrote something like:

```
String word3 = word1.Contact(word2);
```

It is supposed to make `word3` to be like `word1+word2` but the program failed when I ran it.

When I wrote:

```
cout << word1.Contact(word2).Length();
```

...it printed only the `word`1's length, instead of the combined length.

Comment: To be able to help you, we need to know exactly what goes wrong, just "doesn't work" is a very vague description. Also if you can create a shorter example which demonstrates the problem (make sure it compiles and runs) you will get more answers.

Comment: "iv'e implement my own String class" - ohgodwhyyyyyy?

Comment: @Dor S - In the `Compare` member function - `for(; *pSRC==*pSTR && *pSRC!='\0';pSRC++,pSTR++)`. What if `pSRC` is pointing to **abcd** and `pSTR` to **ab** ? The condition that `*pSRC != '\0'` is not satisfied but incrementing `pSTR` after the second iteration invoking *undefined behavior*. You always expect the `pSRC` is greater than or equal to length of `pSTR`.

Comment: ok i just changed it to:  for(; (*pSRC==*pSTR) && (*pSRC!='\0' && *pSTR!='\0');pSRC++,pSTR++)

Comment: @jalf : Don't freak out... :-) ... Perhaps it is for learning purposes... Seriously, who among use didn't try to write a version of <string.h> (check) or a personal version of the string object (check) just to learn C/C++?... :-P ... Now, if this is for production code, let me join "OhRichardDawkinsWhyyyyyyy!!!" (I'm atheist)

Comment: Does your `String` class store its own length? You do not alter this in `Concat()`. Also `Concat()` takes a `const char*`, not another `String`. I hope you're doing this as an exercise, because there's no room for another `String` implementation in production code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the following code:

```
int index = 0;
for(; index < original_str_size; index++)
{
    if(index < original_str_size)
        m_str[index] = str_copy[index];
    else
        m_str[index] = string[index];
}
```

Look at your loop condition, then look at your if condition. Clearly the else block will never execute, and your string is never concatenated.

To fix this problem, your loop condition should be replaced with `needed_length`. Then you would have to replace `string[index]` with `string[index - original_str_size]` to get the correct index in `string`.

Your code should look like this:

```
int index = 0;
for(; index < needed_length; index++)
{
    if(index < original_str_size)
        m_str[index] = str_copy[index];
    else
        m_str[index] = string[index - original_str_size];
}
```

---

On a side note, what does `str_copy` point to? Is it valid memory? Did `del()` free the memory? Might want to check that.

Comment: i've change the code to your answer's code. still not working. my del() code is like that: void String::del()
{
 if(m_str != 0)
 {
  delete []m_str;
  m_str = 0;
  m_size = 0;
 }
}

Comment: Well, then you deleted the string pointed to by str_copy too.  Don't call del() and then call `delete[] str_copy` after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Compare, you have a ; after the for loop, this means the loop does nothing. Also you are returning 0 when the first character matches.

In Concat, you are making str_copy = m_str, then presumably deleting m_str and creating a new m_str. then you copy from the deleted m_str to the new m_str, you may get lucky, but I would not rely on this.

Comment: the Compare is ok. About the Contact - what should i do for fix this "Not 4 Sure" thing?

Comment: you would need to take a copy of the original m_str first. Or in other words, create a temporary char * and new up the right amount. Do all your copying and appending (take note of @Marlon as well), then delete m_str, then make m_str = temporary.

Comment: Also, the Compare was not ok.

Comment: Also now you have edited the question your title is wrong. And a lot of the context of my answer is not there.

Comment: iv'e change the code and now i initialize the 'copy' with the original string.. like that:   String str_copy(m_str);   ... it is correct to write thats way?

Comment: I'm not sure, basically I think you need to go back to the beginning and try to work out what you want to do line by line.

Answer (score 0):

In the your Concat function, it looks like you are deleting the memory which contains your original string before copying the string out of that memory into the newly allocated memory.

Comment: So how can i copy the sring out and to the alolocated thing so it will work?